# docker container "post start" activity

Tags: docker

I'm new to docker and I'm starting of building, deploying, and maintaining telemetry like services (grafana, prometheus, ...).  One thing I've come accross is that I have a need to start up grafana with some default/preconfigured settings (dashboard, users, org, datasources, ...).  Grafana allows some startup configuration in its config file but not with all its features (users, org, ...).  Outside of (if I weren't using) docker I use a ansible script to configure the not supported parts of grafana.  However, when I build my custom grafana image (with allowed startup config) and later start a grafana container of that image is there a way to specify "post-start" commands or steps in docker file?  I image it to be something like every time a container of my image is deployed some steps are issues to configure that container.
Any suggestions?  Would I still need to use ansible or other tools like this to manage it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is trickier than it sounds.  Continuing to use Ansible to configure it post-startup is probably a good compromise between being straightforward, code you already have, and using standard Docker tooling and images.

If this is for a test environment, one possibility is to keep a reference copy of Grafana's config and data directories.  You'd have to distribute these separately from the Docker images.

```sh
mkdir grafana
docker run \
  -v $PWD/grafana/config:/etc/grafana \
  -v $PWD/grafana/data:/var/lib/grafana \
  ... \
  grafana/grafana
...
tar cvzf grafana.tar.gz grafana
```

Once you have the tar file, you can restart the system from a known configuration:

```sh
tar xvzf grafana.tar.gz
docker run \
  -v $PWD/grafana/config:/etc/grafana \
  -v $PWD/grafana/data:/var/lib/grafana \
  ... \
  grafana/grafana
```

---

Several of the standard Docker Hub database images have the ability to do first-time configuration, via an entrypoint script; I'll refer to the [`mysql` image's entrypoint script](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/6659750146b7a6b91a96c786729b4d482cf49fe6/8.0/docker-entrypoint.sh) here.  The basic technique involves:

1. Determine whether the command given to start the container is to [actually start the server](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/6659750146b7a6b91a96c786729b4d482cf49fe6/8.0/docker-entrypoint.sh#L326), and [if this is the first startup](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/6659750146b7a6b91a96c786729b4d482cf49fe6/8.0/docker-entrypoint.sh#L341).
2. [Start the server](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/6659750146b7a6b91a96c786729b4d482cf49fe6/8.0/docker-entrypoint.sh#L90), as a background process, recording its pid.
3. [Wait](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/6659750146b7a6b91a96c786729b4d482cf49fe6/8.0/docker-entrypoint.sh#L93-L104) for the server to become available.
4. Actually do the first-time initialization.
5. [Stop](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/6659750146b7a6b91a96c786729b4d482cf49fe6/8.0/docker-entrypoint.sh#L119) the server that got launched as a background process.
6. Go on to [`exec "$@"`](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/6659750146b7a6b91a96c786729b4d482cf49fe6/8.0/docker-entrypoint.sh#L363) as normal to launch the server "for real".

The basic constraint here is that you want the server process to be the only thing running in the container once everything is done.  That means commands like `docker stop` will directly signal the server, and if the server fails, it's the main container process so that will cause the container to exit.  Once the entrypoint script has replaced itself with the server as the main container process (by `exec`img it), you can't do any more post-startup work.  That leads to the sequence of starting a temporary copy of the server to do initialization work.

Once you've done this initialization work once the relevant content is usually stored in persisted data directories or external databases.

SO questions have a common shortcut of starting a server process in the background, and then using something like `tail -f /dev/null` as the actual main container process.  This means that `docker stop` will signal the `tail` process, but not tell the server that it's about to shut down; it also means that if the server does fail, since the `tail` process is still running, the container won't exit.  I'd discourage this shortcut.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I was considering something like this but was trying to see if docker had some built in capability that I could specify this.  I guess its not there.  Would be a cool feature to do this.
I guess I can google this but do you know if tools dockerswarm/k8/... have this capability?  I would think its similar to being able to do post start tests or something like that?

Comment: Kubernetes in principle [has a PostStart hook](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/container-lifecycle-hooks/) but "there is no guarantee that the hook will execute before the container ENTRYPOINT"; you still need to manually check for the service to be alive.  Kubernetes also adds the complexity that there are typically multiple replicas of services, so a separately-launched Job or something like a Helm post-start hook (which is typically also a Job) can be a better way to ensure first-time setup is only done once.